# Is there a way to set vertical scrollbar for a div?

Tags: html, css

I put a empty content div into a td tag in a table. It shows as there is only one line in div. If I set the height of the div, when I input more content than it's height, it still keep the same size as it was. How to add a vertical scrollbar when content need to consume more space in the div? Thanks.

Comment: +1 for asking the question in the past- so in present we benefit.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Automatically show scroll bars when content is greater than height and width like this:

```
<div style="overflow:auto;"></div>
```

OR

Show scroll bars at all times like this:

```
<div style="overflow:scroll;"></div>
```

Below is some reference for CSS overflow properties:

[overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

[overflow-x](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp)

[overflow-y](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp)

Comment: `overflow-y` is what I was after :D (although I get the validation warning : `Validation CSS2.11: overflow-y not a known CSS property`) I am certain the version I have is 3.0 yet... what do you think?

Comment: @bonCodigo .... overflow-y is certainly a CSS 3.0 feature.  Perhaps the test tool your using is only validating against CSS 2

Answer (score 12):

Use `overflow`, or `overflow-y`: `auto` | `hidden` | `scroll` | `visible`

```
<div style="max-height:100px; overflow-y:auto"> ... </div>
```

or

```
<div style="max-height:100px; overflow-y:scroll"> ... </div>
```

**NOTE:** `overflow` supported since CSS2, but `overflow-y` - CSS3, Opera 9.6, Safari 3.1

Answer (score 1):

If you want vertical scrollbar then

```
<div style="overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

only vertical scroll

```
<div style="overflow-y:auto;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

do this in css

```
div {overflow: scroll}
```

**edit:** What's with all the inline styles guys :-(