# Load External HTML into DIV with internal scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How do I load an html file into a hidden div such that it has a vertical scrollbar, then fade that div in?

Comment: i've just made the div, i believe I need to use the .load function but idk how to make it scrollable

Comment: to make a div scrollable you have to set `style='overflow:scroll;'` on your div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this!

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#nav li a').click(function(){  
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href');  
        $('#main').hide('fast',loadContent);   
        function loadContent() {  
            $('#main').load(toLoad).show();  
        }  
        return false; 
    });  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. It uses jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#myID").click(function(){
        $("#mydiv").fadeToggle(""); /* For both Fade in and Out */
        $("#mydiv").fadeIn(""); /* For both Fade in only */
    });
});
</script>
<a href="#" id="myID">Fade In</a>
<div style="display:none; overflow-y: auto; height: 120px; width:300px;" id="mydiv">
/* Your HTML goes here */
</div>
```

You can get more information in [jQuery Site](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)

Answer (score -2):

http://api.jquery.com/load/

http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

[Is there a way to set vertical scrollbar for a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698741/is-there-a-way-to-set-vertical-scrollbar-for-a-div)

Comment: Upvoting because you and Semthan do not deserve a downvote.