# Scroll not working?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a scroll working on my page. When I add overflow-y: scroll. it makes the content inside the div section completely disappear. 
The CSS I currently have in for the div section is: overflow-y: scroll, height: 100%. Am I missing something?

```
<div id = "section">
        <div id = "map">
            <h1 align = "center">Find Us!</h1>
            <div id = "map-canvas"></div>
            <p>

            </p>
        </div>
        <div id = "form">
            <form method="post" action="mailto: jbloggs@ait.ie">
                <fieldset>
                    <h1 align="center">Contact Us</h1>
                    <table class="contacttable">
                        <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                            <td>First Name</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="firstname"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                            <td>Surname</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="lastname"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Address Line 1</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="addressline1"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Address Line 2</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="addressline2"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Town</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="town"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>County</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="county"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr align="left" valign="middle">
                            <td><input type="radio" name="sex" value="male"/>Male</td>
                            <td><input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"/>Female</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Date of Birth</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="dob"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#section {
    max-height: 150px; /*add height as you want*/
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Go through this http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

[Is there a way to set vertical scrollbar for a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698741/is-there-a-way-to-set-vertical-scrollbar-for-a-div)

This might helps you :)